# MySQL PHP change text colour depending on output

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have a weeks availability table for a project that i am working on. The table prints everything fine but i need the 'doctorName' field to be certain colours depending on if they are available (green) or not (red). So to make it clearer please have a look at this screenshot - https://www.dropbox.com/s/ikxww1yqy10198j/Screen%20Shot%202015-12-05%20at%2010.23.55.png?dl=0

As you can see the second column prints out the 3 doctors names at each time slot and if the doctor has an appointment like at Wednesday at 10am with Moe it prints out the timeSlotId. I am trying to figure out how to get the doctors name in the second column to be red if the doctor has an appointment and green if not. If doctor is available it leaves the field null hence why there are loads of fields empty, i don't have much dummy data as of yet.

This is the if statement that is printing out my table:

```
$results = @mysqli_query ($conn, $query);
//$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($results);

if ($results) {
    echo '<table>
    <tr> <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>The Time</stong>     </font></td> <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Doctor Name</stong>   </font></td> <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Monday</stong>   </font></td> <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Tuesday</stong>   </font></td> <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Wednesday</stong>   </font></td> <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Thursday</stong>    </font></td> <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Friday</stong>  </font></td> </tr>';

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     echo '<tr><td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff">' . $row['theTime'] .    '</font></td> <td bgcolor="#bababa">' . $row['doctorName'] . '</td> <td    bgcolor="#9f9f9f"><font color="#fff">' . $row['bMon'] . '</font></td> <td    bgcolor="#9f9f9f"><font color="#fff">' . $row['bTue'] . '</font></td> <td    bgcolor="#9f9f9f"><font color="#fff">' . $row['bWed'] . '</font></td> <td    bgcolor="#9f9f9f"><font color="#fff">' . $row['bThu'] . '</font></td> <td    bgcolor="#9f9f9f"><font color="#fff">' . $row['bFri'] . '</font></td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>'; 

    mysqli_free_result ($results);  
} else {
    echo '<p class="error">There are no patient's.</p>';
}
```

Would i need to create another if statement under this one? 
"if cell null change doctor name to green, else change doctor name red".
I have tried searching online and couldn't find anything. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So if a particular doctor is booked for the entire week(monday to friday), then the doctor's field would marked as red, otherwise green, right?

Comment: Yes. So if you have a look at the screenshot. On wed at 10am doctor Moe has an appointment. Moe should be red,  curly and larry should be green. Hope that makes sense..

Comment: But if you set Moe red at 10am, it seems that he hasn't free time at 10am all days of the week, but he has. I think that is what was confusing to @RajdeepPaul as well. Maybe it would be better to set the background colour of the appointment cells instead of the doctor name cells, doesn't it? Just a suggestion.

Comment: @nanocv This is exactly what I thought.

Comment: @Tuks Please take a closure look at nanocv's comment and my answer. Rather than setting `DoctorName`'s field as red or green, it would be better if you set background colour of the appointment cells as red or green. My answer is based on this concept.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, i had realised while i was at work that my way wasn't going to work, your code works perfectly, thank you for your help :) @RajdeepPaul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$results = @mysqli_query ($conn, $query);
//$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($results);

if ($results) {
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr> 
            <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>The Time</stong></font></td> 
            <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Doctor Name</stong></font></td> 
            <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Monday</stong></font></td> 
            <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Tuesday</stong></font></td> 
            <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Wednesday</stong></font></td> 
            <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Thursday</stong></font></td> 
            <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Friday</stong></font></td> 
        </tr>
    <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><?php echo $row['theTime']; ?></font></td> 
                <td bgcolor="#bababa"><?php $row['doctorName']; ?></td> 
                <td bgcolor="<?php if(empty($row['bMon'])){ echo '#00ff00'; }else{ echo '#ff0000'; } ?>"><font color="#fff"><?php echo $row['bMon']; ?></font></td> 
                <td bgcolor="<?php if(empty($row['bTue'])){ echo '#00ff00'; }else{ echo '#ff0000'; } ?>"><font color="#fff"><?php echo $row['bTue']; ?></font></td> 
                <td bgcolor="<?php if(empty($row['bWed'])){ echo '#00ff00'; }else{ echo '#ff0000'; } ?>"><font color="#fff"><?php echo $row['bWed']; ?></font></td> 
                <td bgcolor="<?php if(empty($row['bThu'])){ echo '#00ff00'; }else{ echo '#ff0000'; } ?>"><font color="#fff"><?php echo $row['bThu']; ?></font></td> 
                <td bgcolor="<?php if(empty($row['bFri'])){ echo '#00ff00'; }else{ echo '#ff0000'; } ?>"><font color="#fff"><?php echo $row['bFri']; ?></font></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
    </table>
    <?php
    mysqli_free_result ($results);  
} else {
    echo '<p class="error">There are no patient's.</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is only two colors, i would use [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for that (something like that):

```
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><?= $row['theTime'] ?></font></td>
        <td bgcolor="#<?= ($apointment ? '#66cc00' : 'cc0000') ?>"><?= $row['doctorName'] ?></td>
        <td bgcolor="#9f9f9f"><font color="#fff"><?= $row['bMon'] ?></font></td>
        <td bgcolor="#9f9f9f"><font color="#fff"><?= $row['bTue'] ?></font></td>
        <td bgcolor="#9f9f9f"><font color="#fff"><?= $row['bWed'] ?></font></td>
        <td bgcolor="#9f9f9f"><font color="#fff"><?= $row['bThu'] ?></font></td>
        <td bgcolor="#9f9f9f"><font color="#fff"><?= $row['bFri'] ?></font></td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple answer for checking if they have an appointment in whole week or don't have.
`if(empty($row['bMon']) && empty($row['bTue']) && empty($row['bWed']) &&`
`empty($row['bThu']) && empty($row['bFri'])) {`
  `echo '<td bgcolor="green">' . $row['doctorName'] . '</td>';`
`} else {`
  `echo '<td bgcolor="red">' . $row['doctorName'] . '</td>';`
`}`
Hope it helps.